# Python: Why doesn't this work? (iteration over non-sequence)

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, sequence

I have a dictionary with each key containing a list as a value. And I'm trying to go over all the items in the lists, and let's say I'm trying to print all the items as I go through, I wrote:

```
for item in aDict: 
    for item2 in aDict[item]: 
        print item2
```

This prints out the items in the list for the first value, then it gives me an error saying "iteration over non-sequence". Why is this and how should I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note (doesn't solve your problem): Use `iteritems()` instead: `for (i, lst) in aDict.iteritems(): for item2 in lst: ...`

Comment: I suspect @StevenRumbalski and @Ben hit the nail on the head for this one.  You might try inserting a print statement between the two `for`-loops as a way to figure out what exactly is in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming one of the items in `aDict` is not a [sequence](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), string, list, tuple etc:

```
>>> aDict = { 'a' : [1, 2, 3,], 'b' : [4, 5, 6,], 'c' : [7, 8, 9,] }
>>> for item in aDict:
...     for item2 in aDict[item]:
...         print item2
...
1
2
3
7
8
9
4
5
6
>>>
```

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't see this one key that had an integer value.. I should've been more careful... :( Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 7):

One of your dictionary values is not a list!

Comment: Oh shoot I didn't see this one key that had an integer value.. I should've been more careful... :( Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
for item in aDict: 
    for item2 in aDict[item]: 
        print item2
```

Your saying, for each `item` in the dictionary, loop through the `item` index in the dictionary, which doesn't make any sense.

What you really want to do is for each `item`, loop through that specific item, like:

```
for item in aDict: 
    for item2 in item: 
        print item2
```

or using better terms:

```
for dictIndex in aDict: 
        for item in dictIndex: 
            print item
```

Comment: No, that's not it.  `for item in aDict` iterates over *keys*.  So he really does need to do `aDict[item]`.  (Or just do `for item in aDict.values():`)

Answer (score 0):

`aDict[item]` implies that you want the values of the dict, not the keys?  In which case `.itervalues()` or `.iteritems()` should be more natural than the default iteration (over keys only).

```
for key, value in aDict.iteritems():
    for subvalue in value:
        pass
```

The error points to (at least one of) your values is not iterable.

Comment: Better to use itervalues if you're not going to do anything with the keys.